# Sagepay Direct and Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, opayo

I'm looking to integrate Sagepay Direct, their onsite payment gateway option but I've read that it requires an SSL certificate for secure data transfer. Is the Cloudflare pro DNS SSL a valid option for this payment method or would I need a true onsite SSL?

Answer (score 0):

"Is the Cloudflare pro DNS SSL a valid option for this payment method or would I need a true onsite SSL"

It sounds like that they are requiring that you have a valid SSL certificate directly on your server, something we don't provide (Flexible would only do so between browser and our network). This really explains the difference in the [SSL options](https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22046881-What-do-the-three-SSL-options-off-Flexible-Full-mean-).